# Minorant principle for function $\frac{\ln(x)} x$

Tags: real-analysis, divergent-series

I am trying to use minorant principle on:

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(x)} x \, dx$$

It's easy enough to integrate and figure out that the integral diverges, but is there a function that is smaller than the this and for which the sum diverges clearly?

I am trying to avoid integration as best as I can.

Comment: $$\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(x)}{2x}dx$$

Comment: if we look at $\int_e^\infty \frac {\ln x}{x}.$  Since $\frac {\ln x}{x} \ge \frac {1}{x}$ and $\int_e^\infty \frac {1}{x}$ diverges, $\int_e^\infty \frac {\ln x}{x}$ diverges.

Comment: $\frac{\log x}{x}$ has a pretty obvious unbounded primitive, namely $\frac{1}{2}\log^2(x)$.